# Dialogflow: Invoke Follow-up Intent without adding training data

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to build a questions and answers app in Dialogflow. The problem I am stuck is in asking user questions in sequence.

The tricky part is that we have 40 questions saved in Google Cloud SQL and out of these, the cloud function sends 1 random question.

Now the first follow-up intent with first random question is successfully triggered.

The problem we are facing is in calling the second or further follow-up intent. Since the questions are asked using fulfillment API, hence we are not sure what will be the next question and its answer.

We tried to build a follow-up sequence but it didn't worked. Following is the attached screenshot for reference.

[image]

Seeking help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the next **intent** having trained with a random user input by using **context** linking and **@sys.any** Entity in **Dialogflow** which is used to get the user input i.e **Training Phrases in Dialogflow** having any random phrases or text.

[Image reference for Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNxzd.png).

[Image reference for context linking of a question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hw9N.png)

[Image reference for context linking with previous question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP4dI.png)